# Java HTML (twitter) parsing

Tags: java, html, parsing, selenium, twitter

I am parsing a website where the content is usually some tweets, so I want to get only the tweets, I checked the web site structure and the peace of code from I want to get the information from is like the following:

```
<div class="tweet">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/Sweden" target="_blank" class="tweet__link">@sweden</a>
    <span class="tweet__timestamp"><a href="https://twitter.com/sweden/status/691294898453110784" target="_blank" class="tweet__permalink">Jan. 24, 2016, 5:22 p.m.</a></span>
    <p class="tweet__content">None of them should count when it comes to how you get treated by authorities. <a href="https://t.co/NdSZd3YBTk" rel="nofollow">https://t.co/NdSZd3YBTk</a></p>
</div>
```

I want to get everything that is inside the 
I have tried with the following code but I didn't succeed.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://curatorsofsweden.com/curator/aleksandra-boscanin/");

        By tweetSelector = By.cssSelector("div[class='tweet'] a");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(tweetSelector));

        List<WebElement> tweetElements = driver.findElements(tweetSelector);
        for (WebElement tweetElement : linkElements) {
            String tweet= tweetElement.getAttribute("p class");

                System.out.println("Tweet" + tweet);


        }
        driver.quit();
        }
```

Comment: What error you are getting, what do you exactly want to print in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Your `cssSelector` and `getAttribute` are wrong. To find child by cssSelector you need to use `>` `By.cssSelector("div[class='tweet'] > a");`, and `getAttribute` doesn't get tags as parameter, only attributes as "class", "id", "href" etc.

Try

```
List<WebElement> tweets = driver.findElements(By.className("tweet")); //find all the <div> tags

for (WebElement tweet : tweets) {
    List<WebElement> tweetContent = tweet.findElements(By.xpath("*")); //find all intimidate children of the <div>

    String href = tweetContent.get(0).getAttribute("href"); //get href of the first <a>
    String timeStamp = tweetContent.get(1).findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText(); //get the content of the <a> in <span>
    String tweet = tweetContent.get(2).findElement(By.tagName("a")).getText(); //get the content of the <a> in <p>

}
```

This will iterate over all the tweets in the page and extract the content.